# Only allow text from a spreadsheet to be submitted into the text field of a google web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to only allow the names from a spreadsheet to be typed into a Google Script web app. I already have a feature on the app that is called autocomplete which allows the user to type a name and drop-down appears below the input to suggest possible values for the text field. These are the same names that I want to only allow to be typed into and thus submitted with the form. Right now can already pull the names from the spreadsheet as I doing that with the autocomplete feature.

For example
If I have Jack and Jill in my spreadsheet, how can I prevent someone from entering john into the form?

Comment: I think that you should start by reading [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: @pguardiario i have 80 students so a that would be a lot for a dropdown which is why I really liked the autocomplete feature. This is what the autocomplete feature is  [link](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the onsubmit might look like:

JS:

```
var validOptions = ['John', 'Mary']
var formCallback = function(){
  if(validOptions.indexOf($('input#myInput').val()) === -1){
    alert('Wrong!')
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="formCallback()">
  <input id="myInput">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will  only allow you to submit words that are in Sheet1 Column 1.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="txt"name="text" oninput="checkWord();" />
      <br /><input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onClick="saveText(this.parentNode);" disabled />
    </form>
    <script>
      var wA;
      $(function(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){
          wA=obj;
        })
        .getWords();
      });
       function checkWord() {
         $('#sub').attr("disabled",true);
         var word=$('#txt').val();
         //console.log(wA);
         if(wA.indexOf(word)!=-1) {
           $('#sub').attr('disabled',false);
         }
       }
       function saveText(obj) {
         google.script.run.saveWord(obj);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function getWords() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Sheet1
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column1
  const vs=rg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  return vs;
}

function saveWord(obj) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(obj.text);
}
//Using a dialog instead of a webapp
function showMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'Submit Dialog');
}
```